# Hbase Master turing off after start. Setup for Hbase on Hadoop for a single cluster DB on my local machine

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have installed Hadoop (2.9.1) and Hbase (2.1) on my linux machine with the appropriate configurations.

1) I start all hadoop components. Using jps, I am able to see all the components that are running. This step is working fine.

2) When I start hbase, all the hbase components start again . Using the jps command, I am able to see the required components are running again. However, within 10 seconds, **Hmaster** turns off.

This is the contents of  the log file for hbase master:- 
The errors outlined below are pretty much the same for both master and regionserver log file.

```
2018-08-17 17:13:14,255 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
```

I understand that there is some port connection problem, but don't quite know what and where to make the changes.

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: See your zk service is running, are you running a separate service of zk or hbase embedded zk. ?

Comment: @ShivaKumarSS only Hquorumpeer from hbase is running. I am using the zookeeper which is embeded in hbase. Please advice on what to do.

Comment: what is the value given for "hbase.zookeeper.quorum" and "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort" in hbase-site.xml ?

Comment: @ShivaKumarSS    zookeeper.clientport = 2181 and quorum is set to my ipaddress. After changing quorum to my ip address, my error now is  **2018-08-20 10:33:30,473 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine: Region server exiting java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Regionserver: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer**

Comment: Can you share complete stack trace of error.  also try quorum as "localhost" once ?